# Strange NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

I have four classes:
`PointMass`, which inherits from `PropPhysics`, which inherits from `Entity` (`PropPhysics` and `Entity` are both abstract classes), and `World` which has a `List<Entity>` called `Entities`.

Here, I'm trying to add a PointMass to a World's `List<Entity>`.

Strangely, whenever I try to add a new, globally defined, or even existing `PointMass` (within the method's scope), I get a "`NullReferenceException` was unhandled" error.

I check whether, or not, the PointMass "`pMass`" is null, but it is not, and it raises the same error.

I even display a message box whenever a `PointMass` is constructed, but it still raises the same error.

No luck was found from other research.

```
    private void Display_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.PositionX = 0;
        p.PositionY = 0;
        p.Mass = 5;

        PointMass pMass = new PointMass();
        if (pMass==null)
        {            
            MessageBox.Show("error: Mass is null");
        }

        MyWorld.Entities.Add(new PointMass());
        MyWorld.Entities.Add(pMass);
        MyWorld.Entities.Add(p); 
    }
```

Comment: It's not strange. Chances are `MyWorld` is null or `MyWorld.Entities` is null. -1: *please use the debugger to remove "Strange" from the equation*

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you forgot to initialize `p`, `MyWorld` or `MyWorld.Entities`.

I assume the latter, so make sure you have code like this in the constructor of `World`:

```
Entities = new List<Entity>();
```

You can very easily find out which variable actually is `null` by using a Debugger. Please do so in the future before posting such a question.

BTW: `pMass` can't be null directly after it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize `MyWorld.Entities` or `p` in your code. Like;

```
Entities e = new List<Entity>();
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. My mistake. Thank you, all.